# How to get existing jQuery to select html inserted into div as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have jQuery code such as this which uses class names as selectors already present in the document:

```
jQuery(".rego-close").click(function(){
    //on-click events       
});
```

I then have an ajax request which generates a large complex string of html and places it via html() function into a div:

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "outputscript.php?event_id="+var1+"&course_id="+var2,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
           jQuery("#data_target_div").html(data);
           //outputs stuff like: "<div class='something' id='something1'><div><a href='#' data-customAttribute='monkey'>Complex html</a><i>stuff</i></div></div>"
      }
});
```

The html loads into the div correctly, however my jQuery selector won't target content inside the newly generated html.

In the past I used event delegation to target new content, such as:

```
$('.container').on('click','.remove',function(){
    alert("remove");
});
```

But I have way too much code to go back and rewrite everything.

Is there an easy way to add a large, multi-nested HTML string to the DOM so that existing jQuery code will be able to target elements inside it?

Thanks

Comment: No you can not. event delegation is only way for this. otherwise write the onclick handler in the attribute along with object of the clicked element.

Comment: ... I was afraid someone was going to say this :(

Comment: try delegate on `data_target_div` like `$('#data_target_div').on('click', 'div', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

See, if this hack works -

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "outputscript.php?event_id="+var1+"&course_id="+var2,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

      var scr = '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>'; //jQuery library
      jQuery('body').prepend(scr); //recall library

           jQuery("#data_target_div").html(data);
           //outputs stuff like: "<div class='something' id='something1'><div><a href='#' data-customAttribute='monkey'>Complex html</a><i>stuff</i></div></div>"
      }
});
```

Comment: Cool idea, but I can't get it to work unfortunately. Plus I wouldn't want to reload the jQuery library on an ajax request. That would put some serious lag time on my script.